# QGIS: action from attribute table doesn't work correctly

Tags: qgis, actions

**My action**

[image]

**From feature form:**
[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**From attribute table**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

It's a bug?
Tested with QGIS 3.28.8, 3.28.9, 3.32.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected `action scopes` are missing the `field` one.

`feature` will be available when you click on a single feature, including the attribute **form**. It has access to the feature's values.

`layer` works on the entire layer, so the action is available even if you haven't clicked/selected a feature and therefore you can't (easily) access a feature's value

`field` is used within the attribute **table** and can access each row's value. Right click on a row to start the action.

Comment: I appreciate the clarity here. However, this does seem like a bug to me. Why shouldn't a feature-scope action have access to the underlying attributes of the feature? Further, why should the [%colname%] syntax work for field-scope actions at all - since they are triggered from a known row/column and support additional variables like field_name/field_value?

This does not seem like the intended implementation.

Comment: After thinking about this for a few, I do see some solid use cases for the [%colname%] syntax in a field scoped action. But, I see no good reason for needing to trigger a feature scoped action from a field in the attribute table. Either way, thank you for clearing this up - I burned an hour trying to figure out what was going on.